# How do you create thick fabric folding over a piece of furniture?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cloth-simulation

How would I model thick folding fabric to drape over a piece of furniture or surface like in   the image attached? Thanks.

Chair with folding fabric over it.
[image: Chair with folding fabric over it.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare an object like that:

[image]

Switch to *Sculpt* mode, choose the *Pose* brush, *Deformation Target > Cloth Simulation, Deformation > Squash & Stretch*:

[image]

Sculpt in order to roll up the mesh:

[image]

Result!

[image]

Comment: thank you so much!!

Comment: Is there any chance you would be able to go through how you made the initial geometry?

Comment: it's just some extrusions to model a low-poly torso, then apply a Subdivision Surface modifier to have a dense topology